# How can I deform image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfiNy.png)

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbqzE.png)

I want to deform them exactly as an image, I tried ClipRRect but it didn't workded.